# Count rows in a dynamic range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider a very simple example of a dynamic range:
[image]

Cell C10 (arbitrary cell):

```
=FILTER(Table1[List1],NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table1[List1],Table1[List2]))))
```

I would like to now know how many rows are in the dynamic range starting at C10. I tried simply:

```
=ROWS(C10)
```

but it returns '1' even when there are more than one rows returned. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNTA` and the [spilled range operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/spilled-range-operator-3dd5899f-bca2-4b9d-a172-3eae9ac22efd) `#`:

In `C10`:

```
=FILTER(Table1[List1],NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table1[List1],Table1[List2]))))
```

In `D10`:

```
=COUNTA(C10#)
```

[image]

Or like your original approach, you can use `ROWS` with the spilled range operator:

```
=ROWS(C10#)
```

Comment: @BigBen Thanks! Just one note that =rows(C10#) also does the trick.

Comment: @BigBen Hm but interestingly it seems like all of the functions that spill that I've just tried (filter(), etc.) return SOMETHING (even if it's an empty string/blank cell), so the count is '1' even when the results of the formula should be interpreted as '0'.

Comment: @BigBen follow up :) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67811792/return-0-for-number-of-rows-in-empty-dynamic-range