# Return 0 for number of rows in "empty" dynamic range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

With a very simple function that returns a dynamic range in A7:

```
=FILTER(Table1[List1],NOT(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Table1[List1],Table1[List2]))),"")
```

[image]

We can count the number of items in the range with the following (as explained here: [Count rows in a dynamic range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67810638/count-rows-in-a-dynamic-range))

```
=rows(A7#)
```

However, when the function returns "no results", as in this case:

[image]

the count is still '1'. Since filter() was returning an empty string (""), I thought this might do it:

```
=COUNTIFS(A7#,"<>""")
```

but it still returns '1' in this case. How can we get the ResultCount to show 0?

Comment: `=IF(A7="",0,ROWS(A7#))`

Comment: @ScottCraner This works - can you explain why my COUNTIFS doesn't do the same thing?

Comment: because countifs does not like it when the formula returns an empty string.  It does not find them equal.  It is looking for a true empty cell.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your List is only Text, you could use

```
=COUNTIF(A7#,"?*")
```

This counts string of 1 or more characters

<sub>FWIW, your attempt with `=COUNTIFS(A7#,"<>""")` isn't what you think it is: the criteria string evaluates to `<>"` so counts string not equal to a single quote mark.</sub>

<sub>To test for not empty string, you would normally use `=COUNTIFS(SomeRange,"<>")`.  This works for regular ranges, but for some reason not with Spill ranges. Interestingly, the invers (count empty strings) *does* work (`=COUNTIFS(SomeRange,"")`).  You could use this as `=ROWS(C7#)-COUNTIFS(C7#,"")`</sub>

Comment: Thanks @chrisneilsen . What would count as "not text"?

Comment: @David "Not text" would be numbers and errors

Comment: Nope - was hoping for something that could handle EVERYTHING - not 'just text' per @Chris Neilsen's soln above.  Sometimes simple is better, and would've proposed "=iferror(IF(A20="",0,A20#),0)" where A20# contains the nifty filter function OP provided. Before commenting further- ask yourself "does this work for all?" Ta, J

Comment: @James what's the point of your comment?  This OPs question was text only, and `=COUNTIF(A7#,"?*")` handles that.  FWIW, the alternative I mentioned `=ROWS(C7#)-COUNTIFS(C7#,"")` _does_ handle everything.

Comment: Don't be so touchy, just because the example included only text it was not robust.  Ahh - I didn't see that last part.  point.

Comment: (fyi - =ROWS(C7#)-COUNTIFS(C7#,"") fails to handle errors...)

Comment: (just trying to contribute learning / robust solutions that can benefit wider audience - not just the stylised example that 'OP' presents - when no mention that this was exhaustive / comprehensive example set. - OP never specified 'purely text' and even if he/she did - robust goes further in my books.  Isn't that the point of StackOverflow? To contribute learning to the benefit of all? honest intentions mate. honest.